# Given a list/array of True/False, how can we label the clusters of True?

Tags: python, list, iteration

Let's say we have a list of values that are only `True` or `False`. What would be the best way to uniquely label each grouping of `True`, that is, the groups of `True` surrounded by entries `False`? (All values `False` should be converted to 0)

```
list1 = [True, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, False, False]
```

In the converted form, this list would be:

```
list1 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0]
```

I was challenged that it is possible to do this quickly and without a for-loop.

Comment: Create a whole new list based on another list without a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an itertools.groupby solution

```
b
# [False, True, True, False, True, True, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True, False]

list(itertools.chain((k * j // 2 for j, (k, g) in enumerate(itertools.groupby(b), 2) for l in g)))
# [0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0]
```

without the word `for`

```
sum(map(lambda jkg: [jkg[1][0] * jkg[0] // 2] * len(list(jkg[1][1])), enumerate(itertools.groupby(b), 2)), [])
# [0, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0]

# OP's example
sum(map(lambda jkg: [jkg[1][0] * jkg[0] // 2] * len(list(jkg[1][1])), enumerate(itertools.groupby(list1), 2)), [])
# [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 5, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I dunno, I see `for` twice in that … How about `list(itertools.chain(*map(lambda s: map(lambda x: x * s[0]//2,s[1][1]), enumerate(itertools.groupby(b), 2))))` so we can *really* pretend there are are no loops? ;-)

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus Thanks, I arrived at more or less the same. Yours is slightly more elegant. Hm, actually, it doesn't work on my example ;-(